SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) Projects Installation fatal error (0x80070643)
How are you? I need help installing the Visual Studio add-in for SQL Server Integration Services Projects (SSIS).
I leave the log that I get and the error that appears in the installer.


TrycheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed. Error irrecuperable durante la instalación
Apply Complete result 0x80070643 restart: None, ba requested start: No
Opening Url: local path here


I searched the blog for answers, but in general they are associated with Windows or SSMS installation, not SSIS.
Thanks.
I tried to install .NET, to repair Visual Studio, to change the language settings, the .NET Windows feature, and I could not solve it.
